# Parsing file into an array

Tags: c, parsing, text-files

Good day. Don't know whether this question has been asked before. Any who, I have a text file with contents like below

```
AP0003;Football;13.50;90
AP0004;Skateboard;49.90;30
```

It is basically,

```
Item Code;Item Name;Price per unit;Quantity
```

I am trying to put the contents of the text file into an array but I've had no luck so far. And, I can't find anything similar on Stack Overflow (or maybe my search parameters is not accurate). Would appreciate any help I can get. Am new to C Programming.

Comment: Looks like your file is in CSV format. You need a CSV parsing library. See for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7827274/whats-the-preferred-library-for-csv-parsing-writing-in-c and all its duplicates.

Comment: I would eventually need to run my code on a Linux server. A CSV parsing library should work on it too right ?

Comment: If the library is applicable for -nix systems you should be able to run it on a linux machine as well. Otherwise, if you access to the sources, you just recompile it on the linux machine.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly open the file using `fopen`:

```
FILE* fp = fopen("NAME_OF_FILE.txt", "r"); // "r" stands for reading
```

Now, check if it opened

```
if(fp == NULL)                             //If fopen failed
{
    printf("fopen failed to open the file\n");
    exit(-1);                              //Exit program
}
```

Suppose that these are your arrays to store the line and each data are:

```
char line[2048];                          //To store the each line
char itemCode[50]; 
char item[50];
double price;
int quantity;                             //Variables to store data
```

Read the file using `fgets`. It consumes line by line. Put it in a loop which terminates when `fgets` returns `NULL` to scan the whole file line by line. Then extract data from the scanned line using `sscanf`. It, in this case, will return 4 if successful:

```
while(fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp) != NULL) //while fgets does not fail to scan a line
{
    if(sscanf(line, "%[^;];%[^;];%lf;%d", itemCode, item, price, quantity) != 4) //If sscanf failed to scan everything from the scanned line
            //%[^;] scans everything until a ';'
            //%lf scans a double
            //%d scans an int
            //Better to use `"%49[^;];%49[^;];%lf;%d"` to prevent buffer overflows
    {     
         printf("Bad line detected\n");
         exit(-1);                          //Exit the program
    }
    printf("ItemCode=%s\n", itemCode);
    printf("Item=%s\n", item);
    printf("price=%f\n", price);
    printf("Quantity=%d\n\n", quantity);    //Print scanned items
}
```

Finally, close the file using `fclose`:

```
fclose(fp);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main() 
{
 char str1[1000],ch;
 int i=0;
 FILE *fp;
 fp = fopen ("file.txt", "r"); //name of the file is file.txt
 while(1)
   {
    fscanf(fp,"%c",&ch);  
    if(ch==EOF) break;   //end of file
    else str[i++]=ch;    //put it in an array
    }    
 fclose(fp);   
 return(0);
}
```

This will put your entire file into an array str including '\n' and other special characters.If you dont want the special characters put neccessary conditions in the while loop.

Comment: Anyway do you really want everything from the file into your array? I mean what good would that do you?

Comment: Well basically, my assignment requires me to create a purchasing system. So, I would need to compare a user input with the "itemCode" in the file. Trying to figure out what's the best way to go about doing that...

Comment: Then you would not be needing to write the whole file to the array but just the item code.